# I get the wrong result using IBK in weka

Tags: weka, knn

I have two data set, one for training data set and another for test data set. 
I want to find the first nearest neighbor of the first instance of test data set among training data set, I wrote the following code:

```
data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);
data1.setClassIndex(data1.numAttributes() - 1);
IBk knn = new IBk();
String[] options = new String[2];
options[0]= "-E";
options[1]= "-I";
knn.setOptions(options);
knn.setKNN(1);
knn.setCrossValidate(true);
knn.buildClassifier(data);
int d = knn.getKNN();
Double c = knn.classifyInstance(data1.instance(0));
System.out.println(d);
System.out.println(c);
```

I don't know why I get the wrong result. Because the instance that I am looking for the nearest neighbor for, is in training set as well and the result should be the same value as the test instance , but it is not!
My Training dataset:

```
@relation MyRelation

@attribute Fname {Tina,Alex,Poul,Johan,Sarah}
@attribute Lname {Sansed,Erikson,Nadi,Raj,Maad}
@attribute Status {Single,Maried}
@attribute sex {Fmale,male}
@attribute 'worked years' numeric
@attribute age numeric
@attribute Adults numeric
@attribute tax numeric
@attribute salary numeric

@data
Tina,Sansed,Single,Fmale,14,35,5,362.79,1332.5
Alex,Erikson,Maried,male,14,40,6,0,1245.3
Poul,Nadi,Maried,male,6,35,6,207.32,1150.8
Johan,Raj,Maried,male,29,48,5,0,959
Sarah,Maad,Single,Fmale,16,42,2,0,667.1
```

Now in Test data set I want to determine the nearest neighbor for instance:
 Johan,Raj,Maried,male,29,48,5,0,959

The Result of running the code is:

```
1
1332.5
```

It gives me the first instance of the training set every time that I try!

Comment: data :training set                                           data1:Test set

Comment: In order to help we need more information.  It would be super helpful to have small samples of your training and test data that exhibit the problem.  Could you explain in detail how you know that the nearest instance isn't being found?  It seems to me that if the test instance you are looking for the neighbors of is in the training data, then the nearest neighbor of the test instance will be its training data counterpart.  Is that not the case?